# Minimizing a function with summation

Tags: calculus, statistics, optimization

I'm looking to minimize:

$$F(m,b) = \sum_{i=1}^n (mx_i + b -y_i)^2 $$

By taking first order conditions $w.r.t$  **m**, I find:
$$\begin{align*} \frac{\partial F}{\partial m}= 2 \sum_{i=1}^n x_i(mx_i+b-y_i) &=0 \\
\ 2m\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2+2b\sum_{i=1}^n x_i -2\sum_{i=1}^n y_ix_i &=0\\
\end{align*}$$
By dividing everything by 2 and rearranging:

$$m\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2+b\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \sum_{i=1}^n y_ix_i$$

Finally I find that
$$ m = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_ix_i - b\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2} $$

However, this answer seems strange to me as I am unsure about the math.
Can this be simplified further?

Comment: Your first term should be $m\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2$

Comment: @Ripi2 I have fixed this issue and edited original question. Do you feel that the rest of the math is accurate?

Answer (score -1):

Yes the Math is correct. You minimize the equation wrt m to get the minimum point equation for m. Since the equation wrt to m is the form (f(m))^2 or g(f(m)) where g(x)=x^2, we use the chain rule to get 2 * (f(m)) * df/dm or dg/dm * (f(m)) * df/dm

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).